# Merging letters and shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a bumper sticker where a lacrosse stick overlaps a letter that has some transparent parts, as shown in the picture (which looks like a png but the actual file is a vector). How can I get it so that the stick part is not showing in the transparent parts of the letter?

I am running Illustrator CC :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Pathfinder's Divide function will help you here.

1. Before beginning, make sure your text is converted to outlines. Click and drag over your text to select it, then go to **Type > Create Outlines**
2. Select the lacrosse stick(s) and move them behind the text **Object > Arrange > Send to Back**

[image: move shape to back]

3. **Be sure the lacrosse stick(s) are in the final position**, because it will be a little difficult to reposition/adjust after the following steps.
4. With the lacrosse stick(s) behind the letters, choose **Select > All**
5. Go to **Window > Pathfinder** select **Divide** in the Pathfinder panel (it should be the first choice under Pathfinder). This will divide the design everywhere the pieces overlap.

[image: divide function]

6. Then go back to your design with the **Direct Select tool** (white arrow tool) and delete the areas you'd like.

[image: direct select areas to remove]

7. Optional: Once the design is all cleaned, go back and select all the pieces with the Direct Select tool. Then choose **Unite** in the Pathfinder Panel. It will rejoin all those areas to create a complete design.

[image: unite shapes]

**Be careful!** If you don't select the shapes carefully, before hitting **Unite**, you may end up with some wacky results. [Compound paths](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html) can be tricky.